# Momentjs duration is not parsing positive sign correctly

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to add or subtract a `duration` from UTC 0000 hours. `Momentjs` lets one create a duration and then pass that into `add` method. Their documentation mentions that support of mixed negative and positive sign was added in `V 2.13.0`. But using a positive sign is returning 0. The code is available in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kshitij/9jqvfk3g/

```js
const m = moment().utcOffset(0);
m.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0})
m.utc().format('HH:mm')

let d = moment.duration('+03:30').asHours();
console.log('Positive offset: ', d);
console.log('Positive time: ', m.add(d, 'H').format());

let b = moment.duration('-03:30').asHours();
console.log('Negative offset: ', b);
console.log('Negative time: ', m.add(b, 'H').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Momentjs `duration` documentation.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: I agree with you, `moment.duration('+03:30')` creates an empty duration (`P0D`), but I'm not sure it is a bug, maybe you can try to open an issue on [github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues).

Comment: I got around it by removing `+` but I was kind of hoping that such an obvious thing couldn't have been ignored :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in MomentJS. It has been fixed now after my PR was merged - https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/4007

**Edit**
Corresponding Github issue for this - https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4002